# Is it possible to dynamically change image resource path in webpack based on node.js environment

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack in version 4.35.3 with my React app.

I have a react component that I use to import my app logo:

```
import logo from 'images/logo.png';


const AppLogo = () => (
  <image src={logo} alt="myAppLogo" />
);
```

I wish to load a different logo to the app based on the env of the server that build the app.

For example, if I serve the app locally I will get a different logo than I would in production.

I wish to import the image into webpack and not import them through a public accessible path on the server, so there won't be any none relevant images in the app environment.

So I’m trying to solve the issue through the webpack build.

How can I specified the images paths dynamically based on the `process.env.MY_ENV_VAR`?
so I could import

```
 - production
     - images
        - appLogo.png
 - development
    - images
       - appLogo.png
```

My webpack image loading looks like that:

```
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              query: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              query: {
                progressive: true,
                optimizationLevel: 7,
                interlaced: false,
                pngquant: {
                  quality: '65-90',
                  speed: 4,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just had a similar requirement in our angular application.
Kind of late but since I just spend 3 days on this issue it might be useful for others.
The key was the: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-replace-loader

```
File structrure:
 -webapp
    - images

-webapp
   - profile
       - profileA 
          - images
       -profileB
          - images  




{
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot|mp3|pdf)$/i,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader', options: {
                    digest: 'hex',
                    hash: 'sha512',
                    name: 'content/[hash].[ext]'
                }
            }, {
                loader: 'file-replace-loader', options: {
                    condition: 'if-replacement-exists',
                    replacement(resourcePath) {
                        let path = resolve(resourcePath);
                        if (path.indexOf(`webapp${sep}images${sep}`) !== -1) {
                            path = resourcePath.replace(`webapp${sep}images${sep}`, `webapp${sep}profile${sep}${process.env.PROFILE}${sep}images${sep}`);
                        }
                        return path
                    }
                }
            }],
        },
```

Changing the file loader this way we achieved to replace all the files inside the `webapp/images` with the files from the `webapp/profile/[profileNameFromEnv]/images` if it was present.

Important to use the OS based file separator for the checks what you can get from the path `const { sep } = require('path');`

Comment: Thank you! from first look it works with my example, I will try it in my main application